# Rules and Populating Content Fields

Tags: rules, webforms

I have a Temp webform with 2 fields, I have rules set up to, on webform submission, create an entity and then set a data value for the 1 field in my temporary content type[image].

Here is the rule. I have done this exact same thing on another site. The rule creates the entity successfully and pulls the title from the webform submission value of the title field, then when it moves down to setting the data for the second field in the content type it breaks. I am using [data:{component}-value] and replacing {component} with the machine name of the webform field, like I did with the title except it isn't assigning the content field the value I typed and submitted into the webform. Even using the same exact token as i did for the title it does not work. If i used a static just "asdf" to assign to the field of the content type that works, but it will not pull anything from the webform. Any ideas? I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well looks like I was using a slightly old version of Webform Rules, updating solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition, Entity has field: webform>field. I have to do that with entityforms.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I'm confused on what to use on the data section for what you're talking about